# Custom camera UI for wp8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I tried to create an image based app that actually uses camera task when the app is opened. But instead of using the default camera app, I am trying to create a custom UI for the camera like other third-party apps does. Well, my camera UI will be basic, so i would like to know whether this can be achieved within the `CameraCaptureTask` or do i need to create some separate UserControl page?

I am not able to find any resource or samples for this issue. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: You have to stream the camera and should not use tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PhotoCamera` class for this.

[This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx#BKMK_CreatingTheCameraUI) MSDN page clearly explains how to stream and capture images using camera

The code given below shows how to initialize PhotoCamera

```
 PhotoCamera myCamera = new Microsoft.Devices.PhotoCamera(CameraType.Primary);
 //viewfinderBrush is a videobrush object declared in xaml
 viewfinderBrush.SetSource(myCamera);
 myCamera.Initialized += myCamera_Initialized;
 myCamera.CaptureCompleted += new EventHandler<CameraOperationCompletedEventArgs>(camera_CaptureCompleted);
 myCamera.CaptureImageAvailable += new EventHandler<Microsoft.Devices.ContentReadyEventArgs>(camera_CaptureImageAvailable);
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/q/31169881/1392194