# flipped images with front camera for wp8

Tags: windows-phone-8, lumia-imaging-sdk, nokia-imaging-sdk

I am using lumia imaging sdk for my windows phone app. I mainly use the front camera for it. Also am using the `VideoBrush` to capture the images. When I am trying to take picture with front camera, it works perfectly but when the image is captured, the image is flipped and saved(like a mirror effect).

```
<Canvas x:Name="VideoCanvas" Width="480" Height="640" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
    <Canvas.RenderTransform>
        <CompositeTransform ScaleX="-1"/>
    </Canvas.RenderTransform>
    <Canvas.Background>
        <VideoBrush x:Name="videoBrush"/>
    </Canvas.Background>                
</Canvas>
```

The `Scale="-1"` above is helpful for initializing the camera but the capture task storing it as its mirror image. Below is the code that is used to capture the image. Is this mirror effect can be manipulated here?

```
private async Task Capture()
{
        if (!_capturing)
        {
            _capturing = true;

            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();

            CameraCaptureSequence sequence = _dataContext.Device.CreateCaptureSequence(1);
            sequence.Frames[0].CaptureStream = stream.AsOutputStream();

            await _dataContext.Device.PrepareCaptureSequenceAsync(sequence);
            await sequence.StartCaptureAsync();

            _dataContext.ImageStream = stream;

            _capturing = false;
        }
}
```

Or is there any way to flip and save the captured image(like the **LumiaSelfie** app does)? Please help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

In your Lumia Imaging SDK rendering chain you can add a Flipfilter: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lumia.imaging.transforms.flipfilter.aspx

Example:

```
using (var source = ...)
using (var effect = new FilterEffect(source))
using (var renderer = new JpegRenderer(effect))
{
   effect.Filters = new [] { new FlipFilter(FlipMode.Horizontal) };

   var result = await renderer.RenderAsync();
}
```

Comment: This is for applying filter to the captured image. But what i need is, to flip the original captured image while saving it because the image is saved as a mirror(flipped) of it.